# Как пишется слово "право"?

Tags: орфография

> Не дает вам правО указывать на ошибки.

Вопрос - слово "право" пишется с буквой `А` или `О`?

Answer (score 2):

При обозначении конкретных, определённых предметов после отрицания может употребляться и винительный падеж, но при обозначении отвлечённых понятий, как правило, -родительный падеж. Право - отвлечённое понятие.

Так что "Не дает вам правА указывать на ошибки" более корректно.

Answer (score 1):

[Я бы выбрал "А". Грамота.ру тоже предпочитает "А"](http://gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%ED%E5+%E4%E0%E5%F2+%EF%F0%E0%E2%E0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Лучше использовать форму "не дает права".

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

При наличии отрицания Р.п. имеет значение подчеркнутого отрицания, эта форма более строгая, соответствует деловому и общелитературному стилю, она также характерна для отвлеченных понятий (не дает оснований, не скрывает радости, не теряет надежды, не упускает случая).

В.п. возможен, но он ослабляет отрицание и придает речи разговорный характер.

Answer (score 0):

Много лет назад, когда я поступал на филологический факультет университета, в сочинении написал : "...он не имел право". За это мне поставили "4", и пришлось сдавать остальные вступительные экзамены